# Issue installing node.js on a cordova framework

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19043
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\ServiceApp\\WetterStation\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-audit" "--save" "--save-exact" "--loglevel" "error" "react" "react-dom" "react-scripts@0.9.x"
npm ERR! node v18.14.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! core-js@2.6.12 postinstall: `node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the core-js@2.6.12 postinstall script 'node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the core-js package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs core-js
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls core-js
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\****\Desktop\ServiceApp\WetterStation\reactprojectject\npm-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts@0.9.x has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
```

I tryed to install it via

```
npx create-react-app reactproject
```

I already tryed:

- clear cache via command and by deleting it on %AppData%
- changeing the cache path
- reinstalling core-js
- running this through git bash
- deactivate windows setting (proxy)

Im out of ideas, anyone who also has an idea?

Comment: see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8441

Comment: The problem is that i cant change npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT... it doesnt matter if i use the command prompt or if i change my ComSpec